# referencing php variables inside of an array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have a small problem that I cannot seem to wrap my head around and hoping someone here might be able to find the problem. I have an variable named **$data** which is an array of string values and when I use the following code everything works fine.

```
$data = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$users = implode("," , $data);

echo ($users);
```

This will produce something like 1,2,3,4,5 which is what I expected, but if I try to follow the same logic on the following piece of code then the result is an empty string.

```
$data = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$users = implode("," , $data);

$MyArray = array(
    $user_ids => array($users)
)
```

My question then is how do I need to reference the $users variable in this array so it will produce the results I need. (ie 1,2,3,4,5 ...)

Thx,
Amy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want the key to be but right now you are using a variable as a key:

```
$users = implode("," , $data);
$user_ids = 'users_id_keyname';

$MyArray = array(
  $user_ids => $users 
);

echo $MyArray['users_id_keyname']; // outputs 1,2,3,4,5
echo $MyArray[$user_ids]; // outputs 1,2,3,4,5
```

You probably want to just use the string as the key:

```
$users = implode("," , $data);

$MyArray = array(
  'user_ids' => $users 
);

echo $MyArray['user_ids']; // outputs 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by Key and all that but I tried your 2nd example and I received a parse error saying: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '(' in C:\wamp\www\forum\practicepm.php on line 58

Comment: the you have an error somewhere thats not directly part of the code i gave you. You do need to understand what a `key` is when dealing with arrays, though... its kind of essential.

Comment: I updated the code in the original post. I forgot to add the word array in front of ($users) so the old code just said user_ids => ($users) but it now says user_ids => array($users) that may clear up some of the confusion sorry about that.

Comment: @Amy: if you do it that you will actually have the following if you were to var_dump `$MyArray`: `Array('user_ids' => Array( 0 => "1,2,3,4,5"))` is that what you actually want?

Comment: As long as it works I don't care but all I know is I need the word array in front of the ($users) part or I get tons of error messages about missing this and that.

Comment: I will just give you the little check thing since I am sure your answer is fine. I just don't know enough about php and working with someone elses scripts to make use of it.

Comment: Just remove the `()` from $users... there is no need for them really.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '(' in C:\wamp\www\forum\practicepm.php on line 58

Comment: can you post the script? that shouldnt generate an erro unless there is something missing elsewhere. I just ran both versions of the code i posted to doublecheck and it works just fine, so something else must be messed up somewhere in your file.

Comment: The script is actually referencing an API from another much larger script. Unless you have the other script and it is setup the way we have it setup then it will not help you.

Comment: Yes it will because the issue is local to `practicepm.php` we need to see that file, not necessarily the API its using.

Comment: Ok so the script is expecting the `to` field to be an array of user id's so you were right the first round you want to do `array($users)`. My question is it looks like that code was already there what were you trying to modify that lead to your initial question?

Comment: If I run the code as it appears in the script on pastebin then I get an error message which says: An Error Has Occurred!
Database error, given array of integer values is empty. (to_members) ... This lead me to believe that the variable $users is not being sent properly to the array so I was trying to figure out how to get it to send the information it needs

Comment: like I said if I just echo out the $user variable then it shows 1,2,3,4,5 but if I reference it from within that array then I get the error I showed above, All I want to do is populate the array with the information stored in the $users variable. Simple enough I thought, but guess not.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make your data array into a string and convert it back into an array.  You could just insert the array into another array and reference it that way.  For example:

```
$data = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$MyArray[] = $data;
```

To recall this data:

```
foreach($MyArray as $array){
echo implode(',',$array);
}
```

Comment: I need the word array infront of the word users because if I omit it then I get alot of errors.

Comment: I rewrote my answer, and tested this, and it works.  Hope it works for you. Any questions, let me know.

Comment: You all decide who wins the pot, this is getting to confusing to me. I already wasted 2 days on this I think I will let someone else work on this project who knows what they are doing.